# Accessing a NSTableviews custom Tablecellview

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I made a NSTableview and a custom tablecellview-class "KSTablecellview" which defines the cells inside the tableview.

Now I'm trying to access these cells and the elements inside them at a certain time, for example triggered through an users input.

For example I wanna change the text of a textfield in one of my custom cellviews. I tried that:

```
Outlet_TableView.selectRowIndexes(IndexSet(integer: 0), byExtendingSelection: false) // Selecting row #1

let view = Outlet_TableView.view(atColumn: 0, row: 0, makeIfNecessary: false) as! KSTableCellView // getting cellview, at first row/ first column (-> crashes)    
view.myTextField.stringvalue = "Hello World"
```

This fails giving me "[...] [default] Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)"

I tried some other things and tried to work out the problems reason, but I wasn't able to do it, I'm still a beginner.

Any help would be really great.

I'm using XCode and Swift, trying to build an app for Mac OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to avoid updating the content of your cells manually. Instead, you should reload the data from your data source.

```
func reloadData(forRowIndexes rowIndexes: IndexSet, 
                           columnIndexes: IndexSet)
```

Which will in turn fetch the data from your data source at the given index/column.

For example, your data source would probably contain `"Hello World"` at the given index after the user event occurred (provided you updated your data source content), and would thus be used in the `dataCellFor:` delegate method.

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna do it that way then.
Besides the fact that I shouldn't update the cells manually, do you think there is a way to do it? Or is that just impossible?

Comment: You can do it, but once you call reloadData, it'll override your changes if you haven't updated the datasource

Answer (score 0):

May be you're doing these operations before table is loaded for the first time(eg. in`viewDidLoad`) or on `tableView` with `numberOfRows = 0`.

Until `tableView` loads that row, it won't create the views inside that row and `tableView.view(atColumn:, row:, makeIfNecessary: false)` will return `nil` and force unwrapping this `nil` will make your application crash.

Comment: Well right now I'm doing it inside ViewDidLoad() but after super.viewDidLoad(), so it shouldn't be that I guess.

Comment: Even if you call `super.viewDidLoad()` it won't work as`NSTableViewDatasource` methods won't be called by viewDidLoad. It's better to call `tableView.reloadData()` just before calling `tableView.view(atColumn:, row:, makeIfNecessary: false)`

Comment: And also updating the cells manually is also possible but just not advisable. The manual way you're doing in your question will update the cell.

Comment: Ok - I get that using tableview.reloadData is the proper way to do it. I have a problem with that tho. I'm trying to make an element inside a tableview-cell the firstresponder. In order to do that I can't use reloadData because it won't work to set a Cell as firstresponder while it's reloading. 
So I need to access the cell manually from "outside"... but doing that - even outside the ViewDidLoad, for example triggered through pressing a button keeps giving me an error.